# Concatenate an already existing environment variables in IntelliJ Idea Tomcat configuration

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I want to prepend Windows PATH environment variable with something, I then assumed configuring it with that will be fine:

[image: IntelliJ Idea Tomcat configuration]

Adding `PATH` environment variable with `C:\PathOnlyForMyApp;%PATH%`, but it does not works, if I print `System.getenv("PATH")` I see literally what I put in configuration with `%PATH%` not resolved.

Note I also tried `${PATH}` and `$PATH$` without success too.

Anyone knows if it is possible to do this ?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Try to put backslash before `;` If you're on Windows feel free to upvote/comment https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85313 .

Comment: Thanks @EgorKlepikov but unfortunately it just adds a backslash at the end of my path and I just got `C:\PathOnlyForMyApp\;%PATH%` instead of `C:\PathOnlyForMyApp;%PATH%`